# Compare key values within object for duplicate updated

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is a follow up post from [Compare key values within object for duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601041/compare-key-values-within-object-for-duplicate) for a follow up answer.

I have an object:

```
myObj = {
  attendent-0-id:"123",
  attendent-0-name:"Bob Smith",
  attendent-1-id:"1234",
  attendent-1-name:"Alex Smith",
  attendent-2-id:"123",
  attendent-2-name:"Charlie Smith",
  attendent-0-id:"123",
  attendent-0-name:"John Smith",
  attendent-maxGuest:1,
  attendent-party-name:"",
}
```

Thanks to help on here (Rick) I was able to get 90% of the way there.

```
function errorOnDuplicateIds(obj) {
  const map = {};
  const pattern = /^attendent-\d+-id$/;

  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (pattern.test(key)) {      
      const value = obj[key]

      if (value in map) {
        map[value] = [map[value], key];       
      } else {
        map[value] = key
      }
    }    
  }
return map;
}
```

I am getting a return of:

```
array:[
  0:(2) ["attendent-0-name", "attendent-1-name"]
  1:"attendent-2-name"
]
```

but I am looking for:

```
array:[
  0:(2) ["attendent-0-name", "attendent-1-name", "attendent-2-name"]
]
```

The issue I am having is that while this works if there are two matching keys it will not work (Correctly) if there are three or more.

Comment: I believe you should have edited your original question, not create another one.

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't have accepted an answer that doesn't work?

Comment: It did work for what I needed but things have changed. The person who provided said answer asked for a new question to keep things separate.

Comment: It would help to know why it is not working Correctly. What are the expected results when there are three or more of the same id and what is actually given?

Comment: What is the desired behavior when there is more than one match?

Comment: @RyleyAmeden Ah, the question with the updated code is ok as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an array of all matches for each key in you map, you need to start by setting an array when you find a key the first time. On subsequent matches, just push into that array:

```js
const myObj = {'attendent-0-id': "1234",'attendent-0-name': "Bob Smith",'attendent-1-id': "123",'attendent-1-name': "Alex Smith",'attendent-2-id': "123",'attendent-2-name': "Charlie Smith",'attendent-maxGuest': 1,'attendent-party-name': "",};
  
function errorOnDuplicateIds(obj) {
  const map = {};
  const pattern = /^attendent-\d+-id$/;

  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (pattern.test(key)) {
      const value = obj[key]

      if (value in map) {
        map[value].push(key); // push a new value 
      } else {
        map[value] = [key] // set it to an array
      }
    }
  }

  /* if you only want lengths > 1
     otherwise just return map   */
  let filtered = Object.entries(map)
    .reduce((a, [key, value]) =>  value.length > 1 ? Object.assign(a, {[key]: value}) : a, {})

  return filtered;
}

console.log(errorOnDuplicateIds(myObj));
```

If you are only interested in values with more than one hit, you can `reduce()` down to a map with only values of length greater than one, which is what the last bit in the snippet does.

Comment: Great @RyleyAmeden, note that this will return *all* values even those with only one ID. I added an edit that shows a quick way to filter to only dupes.

Comment: I noticed that, thank you! It is giving me an error that .length doesn't exists on {}

Comment: @RyleyAmeden maybe your passing in the wrong thing, not sure. I added it to the snippet so you can see it in action.